# Class.where(obj:"someone") with index.html.erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sql-order-by, erb

I've got some problem with method in tittle. 
I have got:

```
model group title:string 
model user name:string user:references
```

In `index.html.erb` i'm trying to use `<=% User.where(group:"Admins) %>` and then return on localhost/users (address in RAM i guess) - `#<Project:0x007f6f38594af8>.` How can i get just name of user where category is Admins?

UPD: I need to list all users of "Admins" group.

Comment: Please clear your question..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Clear your question. You cannot do `<=% User.where(group:"Admins") %>` because Group is a model.

But you can scope in Model which will give you list of all users of "Admins" group

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :admin_groups, -> {includes(:groups).where(groups: { title: 'Admin') } }
end
```

In your view You can call `<%= User.admin_groups %>`.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Yea, ty, i got it, but with other way.